# Add data to UIView using Categories

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, subclass, objective-c-category

I'd like to extend the iOS UIView class so I can store some of my own data and state within my UIView instances.  I am new to iOS.  I understand that I can't add instance variables to Categories, so presumably I can't add new state to my UIViews.

I am therefore thinking of creating an NSArray, where each of my UIViews has a unique tag which is then used as an index into an NSArray, and where each item in the NSArray holds the additional state information about that particular UIView.  The drawback here is the management of the Tags and the NSArray.  It would be so much more straightforward if I could just add state directly to any UIView via a Category.

Can anyone advise me on the best way to add some instance variables and state to UIViews?  I am using lots of UIView subclasses, and so don't really want to start subclassing UIView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Associative references](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW51) will let you do what you want, though I'm not sure why you don't want to subclass (you already say you have a lot of subclasses - perhaps a better strategy of subclassing would be a better solution?).

Comment: Hi Vladimir - the reason (perhaps wrongly) that I don't want to subclass is that I'm using lots of UI elements (such as UITextField, UIImageView, UIButton etc) and I need each of these (which all derive from UIView) to 'inherit' the data and methods defined in my new extension class.  My understanding is that I can't just subclass UIView because all the existing UI elements (UIView descendants) won't then get the additional behaviour?

Comment: OK, I thought you were making your own subclasses. In that case, associative references can definitely help. Though if you can elaborate more on the type of functionality you want to add to the UIViews, perhaps even a better solution can be found.

Comment: How does it not work? This is a fundamental feature in Apple's Objective C implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UIView.tag` property for that. Its `NSInteger` (long), so you can have a map somewhere else.